# Can I make an argument "required" in a TypeScript function type?

Tags: typescript

The following TypeScript code compiles

```
const f1 = (x: string) => { console.log(x) }
type F2 = (x: string, y: string) => void;

const callF2 = (fn: F2) => {
    fn("a", "b");
}

callF2(f1)
```

So `callF2` expects a function as input that takes two arguments, however I can pass `f1` that takes only one argument. This is sort of fine, because `f1` is *compatible* with the requirements - the second argument will just be ignored.

But I have a scenario, where the 2nd argument is a database transaction. I don't want to be able to pass a function, that ignores the transaction.

Can I do anything to the type definition, or compiler options, that would cause a compiler error for this code?

Comment: Even if someone wrote a linter rule which caught `call2(f1)`, it won't catch `call2((x: string, y: string) => {console.log(x);})` which accepts the argument and *still* ignores it.  There's not much different between those two scenarios, so I'm not sure it's fruitful to try to chase this down.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in TS that has already been extensively discussed.

Your issue is that `const foo:F2 = f1;` is perfectly valid.

The can read the FAQ entry about: [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

And if you want a list of issues talking about it, check [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42749) !

Anyway, your best alternative would be passing all arguments into a single object to ensure you'll get all arguments.

Comment: Yeah, I totally understand _why_ it's valid. And just looking at the FAQ makes it clear that a compiler option is not an option, as it would break a lot of perfectly fine code. So I guess that the answer is really, "No", I can't enforce that the transaction is not ignored with that signature. Then I'd need a different signature, e.g. the transaction is the first argument instead of the 2nd.

Comment: Yeah, having an object with all parameters is probably what you'll want to ensure all parameters are passed !

Comment: Passing an object has the same issues, unless I am missing some subtle difference. The function `f=({x}:{x:string}) => {...}` is compatible with `type F2=(i:{x: string, y: string}) => void`